# Will the external Git repo location be linked to project folder automatically?

Tags: git

I was using git in my project and I did these commands.

```
git init
git remote add myproject1 http://url
```

And now I was able to get the newest updates and commit by these simple commands, never needed to add parameters:

```
git push
git pull
```

Now I started working on another project and used those same 2 commands in my other folder,  only small changes `git add myproject2 http://url2`

When I browse with GIT to my first project or second project, will the GIT know from where to `pull` or where to `push` by default or I must define the project name always? (project1 or project2)

Comment: Are you sure that's what you did? The second form adds some content to be tracked by git, not a remote. I doubt it did anything useful for you.

Comment: Are these two completely separate projects, or is one a fork of the other (i.e. there is common history)? If they're separate projects, and you haven't taken special care to merge the second project in as a subdirectory or something, then you will only have one project visible at a time, depending on which branch you have checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git stores all the metadata for the repository in a directory called `.git`, inside the working copy. So yes, git will know which remote repository to use when you `cd` into a different working copy (project) and do `git push` or `git pull`.